# Android GMail API get Outbox mails

Tags: android, gmail-api

I try to get only mails from Outbox:

```
            String user = "me";
        ListMessagesResponse response = mService.users().messages().list(user).execute();
        //set selected labels
        //[CATEGORY_PERSONAL, CATEGORY_SOCIAL, Регистрации, CATEGORY_FORUMS, IMPORTANT, CATEGORY_UPDATES, CHAT, SENT, INBOX, TRASH, CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS, DRAFT, SPAM, STARRED, UNREAD]
        List<String> labelIds = new ArrayList<>();
        labelIds.add("SENT");
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = mService.users().messages().list(user).setLabelIds(labelIds).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

but I get Inbox messages too

Comment: Why don't you `setLabelIds` on the first `ListMessagesResponse` as well?

Comment: Thank you, @Tholle, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I need to set filter on the first response line.
This code work:

```
String user = "me";
        //set selected labels
        //[CATEGORY_PERSONAL, CATEGORY_SOCIAL, Регистрации, CATEGORY_FORUMS, IMPORTANT, CATEGORY_UPDATES, CHAT, SENT, INBOX, TRASH, CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS, DRAFT, SPAM, STARRED, UNREAD]
        List<String> labelIds = new ArrayList<>();
        labelIds.add("SENT");
        ListMessagesResponse response = mService.users().messages().list(user).setLabelIds(labelIds).execute();

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = mService.users().messages().list(user).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```